# "people who puts ... their mouth is" vs "people who put ... their mouths are"

Tags: idioms, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, relative-clauses

> So you'd say you’re one of those people who *puts* their money where their *mouth is*?

(http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/theenglishwespeak/2012/06/120626_tews_77_put_your_money_where_your_mouth_is.shtml)

Why not

1 "So you'd say you’re one of those people who ***put*** their money where their *mouth is*";

or

2 "So you'd say you’re one of those people who ***put*** their money where their ***mouths are***"?

Comment: "one of" makes it singular. So "puts" is the correct verb. "mouth is" must be singular because one person has only one mouth. But actual usage may be different, due to the "proximity rule". You can search on this term here, on EL&U, or other search engines.

Comment: I'd accept #2 as a valid alternative. It's worth noting that 'put' vs 'puts' also depends on tense.  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put) has a nice list of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both are correct, depending on how you interpret the sentence structure.

"You're one of [those people who put their money]" - people who put, plural.

"You're one (of those people) who puts their money" - you're one who puts, singular.

For the second part, "where their mouths are" vs "where their mouth is", that clause can also simply agree with the first part.

Also, in "their mouth(s)", "their" can be used for both singular and plural, since the whole sentence is about a vague group of "people who do that".